# Interdependent properties within a class

Tags: c#, .net, class, properties

I have the following class which alters the result of a certain query:

```
public class UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions
{
    public Boolean IncludeProperties { get; set; }
    public Boolean IncludeOrganizationUnits { get; set; }
    public Boolean IncludeManagers { get; set; }

    public static UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions All
    {
        get
        {
            return new UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions { IncludeOrganizationUnits = true, IncludeProperties = true, IncludeManagers = true };
        }
    }

    public static UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions None
    {
        get
        {
            return new UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions { IncludeProperties = false };
        }
    }

    public UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions()
    {
        this.IncludeProperties = true;
    }
}
```

The thing is, setting `IncludeOrganizationUnits` to `true` when `IncludeProperties` is `false` does not make sense in my case and same goes for `IncludeManagers` which also depends on `IncludeOrganizationUnits` being set to `true`.

I do not think this is the best way of doing this. So my question is, what pattern can I use to improve this class and make it easier for others to use my class?

**UPDATE:**

Ok so I ended up switching to an `enum` decorated with the `Flags` attribute:

```
[Flags]
public enum UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions
{
    None = 0,
    IncludeProperties = 1,
    IncludeOrganizationUnits = 2 | IncludeProperties,
    IncludeManagers = 4 | IncludeOrganizationUnits
}
```

Comment: "true-ish" makes sense in javascript (commonly referred to as truthy) but what does true-ish mean for a c# boolean??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not an answer: But this kind of cross-rule enforcement is the usual example used by [CodeContract](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) library examples.

Comment: @ken2k: I've updated the thread and included my question at the end.

Comment: @Kassem Is it required for your scenario that a user can set the value of one of the boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to validate the values instead of pure auto properties:

```
public Boolean IncludeProperties { get; set; }

private Boolean includeOrganizationUnits;
public Boolean IncludeOrganizationUnits 
{ 
    get { return this.includeOrganizationUnits }
    set
    {
        if(value && !IncludeProperties)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("IncludeProperties must be true when IncludeOrganizationUnits is set to true");
        includeOrganizationUnits = value;
    }
}
```

This sort of pre-condition can also be configured using [CodeContracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) however be aware there is a [performance hit by doing so](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181411/Code-Contract-Performance-Analysis).

Another option, if the users dont actually need to set those booleans themself is to expand your list of static ones to encompass all (valid) possibilities and make things private (like the setters and ctor):

```
public class UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions
{
    public Boolean IncludeProperties { get; private set; }
    public Boolean IncludeOrganizationUnits { get; private set; }
    public Boolean IncludeManagers { get; private set; }

    // UPDATED !!
    public static UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions OrganizationUnitsAndManagers
    {
        get
        {
            return new UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions { IncludeOrganizationUnits = true, IncludeProperties = true, IncludeManagers = true };
        }
    }

    // NEW!!
    public static UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions OrganizationUnits
    {
        get
        {
            return new UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions { IncludeOrganizationUnits = true, IncludeProperties = true};
        }
    }

    public static UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions None
    {
        get
        {
            return new UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions { IncludeProperties = false };
        }
    }

    private UniversalPrincipalQueryOptions()
    {
        this.IncludeProperties = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is not required for the user to be able to set the value of the properties, then a private constructor is the way to go.

Comment: @ken2k - you mean like the private constructor I put on the class?

Comment: Yes, exactly (but we're still not sure it's the OP's use case)

Comment: I prefer the second option actually. Do you think an `enum` would be better suited for this?

Comment: @Kassem - an enum is another option, possibly with the `Flags` attribute. But you will still need some validation to ensure the right combinations have been set.

Comment: @ken2k, yes the user of the class has the choice of setting the values of the properties. I just need to make it clear to the user that when selecting `IncludeManagers` it also implies that the other properties are being set to true as well.

Comment: Yes, `Flags` is what I'm looking for I guess. I'll look into that.